# HERE Maps Api Reverse Geocode and Street/Road Bearing

Tags: here-api

Using HERE Maps Api, for a geographic coordinate (lat, lng), I would like to find address information for the nearest routable road. Information that includes:

- Address (street, house number, city, postal code, country)
- Bearing/Heading of the road (0 to 360 degrees from True North)

How can I achieve this through HERE Maps API?

So far, this is what I have been able to achieve:

1. Calling the `calculate Route API` with identical start and end endpoints and `mode=car` will force the API to snap to the nearest routable point. This step is necessary for when the input coordinates are for a pedestrian street.
2. Using the nearest routable point coordinates, I can call `reverse GeoCode API` and I will be able to find the address information I need.

The next step is where I'm currently stuck. I'm able to find information like `direction=NW`, however I can't find the ~exact bearing in `grad`, for example `bearing=265`.

**Is this achievable? Are 3 steps really necessary or is there a HERE Maps API endpoint that can provide all of this?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Fleet Telematics API to get the headings value for a particular road. Read more about the api here - https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/quick-start-view-map-data.html
You can also look at the field explanationshere - https://tcs.ext.here.com/pde/layer?region=WEU&release=19111&url_root=pde.api.here.com&layer=ADAS_ATTRIB_FC1

**HEADINGS**    Horizontal road heading [10^-3 degree] at coordinate points along the link, when driving from Reference Node. Comma separated. Each value is relative to the previous. No values here for the ref/nonref nodes, because they are in the separate fields REFNODE_LINKCURVHEADS and NREFNODE_LINKCURVHEADS.